# Breakpoints and maven options are ignored when using spring devtools

Tags: maven, spring-boot-devtools

I'm trying to use spring devtools for my project. When I add devtools dependency breakpoints stopped working and maven options are ignored. I'm using Netbeans. 
I added dependency into pom.xml

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And this is the netbeans action for debug:

```
Executed goal: spring-boot:run
Profile: dev
Properties:
 jpda.listen=maven
 Env.MAVEN_OPTS=-Dflyway.enabled=false
```

Breakpoints and maven options (MAVEN_OPTS) are working fine without devtools dependency. Adding the devtools dependency causes "-Dflyway.enabled=false" option and breakpoints being ignored. The maven command with all arguments generated by Netbeans is the same, I can see it in the log output. Is there anything else I have to set for devtools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, the properties in action must be written this way (spring boot 2.0.0):

```
spring-boot.run.jvmArguments=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address} -Dspring.flyway.enabled=false
jpda.listen=true
```

For spring boot version < 2.0.0 it is:

```
run.jvmArguments=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address} -Dflyway.enabled=false
jpda.listen=true
```